# Origin games on Amazon PC Download service

Tags: origin, digital-distribution

If I buy an Origin activated game on Amazon's PC Download (i.e. *not* key from „PC Instant Access”), what would I actually get?

[image]

According to generic Amazon's page describing „Games Library”, I would need their [downloader software](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201110320). On the game page for „PC Download” option they specify 3 KB (*sic!*) of download. Is that really the case, or would I actually just directly get Origin code?

Comment: I suspect it will depend on what game it is.  The vast majority are probably just game keys.  There's nothing else that fits into 3KB.

Comment: @Frank: true, but then why is it 3KB, that's lot more then just a key. Unless they count whole fancy HTML or whatever ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not straight up game key text.  You have to add in the, "Here's where to use it" stuff and all.  And the HTML fancy formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Just under the name of the game, to the right of the ESRB rating (at least in the US, I don't know about overseas if they show a different rating...) will be a "DRM:" notification.  This notification changes as you select different versions.

If this line reads "DRM: Origin" like on [The Sims 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00166N6SA) you'll get a key to redeem on Origin.

It can also read "DRM: Steam" for EA games that are on Steam, like [Tomb Raider](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007VFHGZ4).  In this case, you'll get a Steam key.

If this "DRM:" is missing, generally that means you'll have to download it directly from Amazon using their downloader.

In the case of Ubisoft games where the "DRM:" line is missing, like the [Far Cry 3 version without Steam DRM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088Q8MXA) they'll generally give you a product key that you can put directly into uPlay and use their downloader if you so desire.

Comment: Seems that it's bit different on Amazon.co.uk, there is no `DRM: ...` thing. Origin example http://www.amazon.co.uk/Battlefield-4-Online-Game-Code/dp/B00E9G39RC/ Steam example http://www.amazon.co.uk/Tomb-Raider-Online-Game-Code/dp/B00DEM5DJO/

Comment: @vartec While the DRM information isn't at the same place at amazon.co.uk, you can find an additional sentence in the item description of the download versions if you scroll down. For Battlefield "*Origin* account required for game activation and installation" and Steam for Tomb Raider.